# How to get the cumsum of a datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a column containing timedelta (timedelta64[ns]) and I want to obtain the cumsum of the column in another column so my original column gives me

```
 Index Timestamp
   0    Nat
   1    00:07:00
   3    00:02:00
   4    00:05:00
   5    00:06:00
   6    00:01:00


 Index Timestamp   cum_Timestamp
   0    Nat            Nat
   1    00:07:00       00:07:00
   3    00:02:00       00:09:00
   4    00:05:00       00:14:00
   5    00:06:00       00:20:00
   6    00:01:00       00:21:00
```

Comment: not recommended  `cumsum` with time delta

Comment: What would be the recommended way to do it @Wen-Ben

Comment: Convert to second , then cumsum the second .

Comment: Check this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html